# How can I pass arbitrary args to a callback function in RabbitMQ?

Tags: python-3.x, rabbitmq

I am trying to pass a callback function in the RabbitMQ `basic_consume` method that requires extra arguments.

For example, the callback function signature in RabbitMQ is:

```
def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    pass
```

I want something like:

```
def callback(ch, method, properties, body, x, y):
    # do something with x and y
```

Then pass it down as a callback in `basic_consume`

```
channel.queue_declare(queue=queue_name, durable=True)
channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
channel.basic_consume(queue=queue_name, on_message_callback=callback)
channel.start_consuming()
```

How can I achieve something like that?

Comment: @LutzHorn, for the most part, x and y are fixed. Can you give an example of currying to generate the callback?

Comment: Use a [lambda function](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/anonymous-function).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) to generate a callback:

```
def generateCallback(x, y):
    def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
        print(
            "callback for ch={}, method={}, properties={}, body={}, x={}, y={} called".format(
                ch, method, properties, body, x, y
            )
        )

    return callback


if __name__ == "__main__":
    callback = generateCallback(1, 2)

    callback("ch", "method", "properties", "body")
```

Output:

```
callback for ch=ch, method=method, properties=properties, body=body, x=1, y=2 called
```